# Возможно ли стать fullstack на React.js + Java?

Tags: java, стек, reactjs

Мне 15 лет, я бы хотел стать full stack разработчиком и пока что я на старте изучения Java. Что можете посоветовать для того чтобы стать хорошим full stack? Востребованы ли React.js/Java в связке?Или придется помимо Java изучать Node.js?

Comment: Придется, куда денешься?

Comment: пока выберите одно направление, да связка React и Java пока котируется, но всё меняется. Хотя суть программирования не меняется. Лично я советую начинать свой путь в программировании с низкоуровневых языков (например C (не C++)), там вы встретитесь лицом к лицу с самыми основами, поймёте что такое типы данных, структуры, условия, циклы. Просто если сразу начинать с Java или JS, все эти вещи остаются за кадром и потом становится всё труднее вернуться к этим основам, чтобы разобраться в них.

Comment: Все возможно, но сейчас вам это не нужно. В 15 лет нужно пробовать делать крутые штуки, в той области которая интересна, а не целиться туда, где большие зарплаты. Потом полученные навыки в любом случае пригодятся, а если начинать сразу со скучных вещей, то лет через 5 вам это сильно надоест.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя есть время попробовать несколько языков C#, PHP, JAVA, RUBY, PYTHON и т.д. Все годятся для фулл. Сильно не заморачивайся (не учи) попробуй все по немногу. Ты увидишь, что они сильно похожи между собой. Одни больше, другие меньше. Через годик поймёшь, какой легче заходит. А ноде, Ангуляр и вообще скрипты учить придётся, без них никуда фулу.